# Problems installing NumPy in Python3.4, but python3.5 is default (MInt

Tags: numpy, python-3.4, linux-mint

I need to work with python3.4 and numpy. My distribution is Mint 18 and python3.5 is the default python version.

So I installed python3.4. But I can't import the module numpy. I tried with `pip`, but I read that `pip-3.4` is no longer working and `pip3` is not helpful, because it is related to python3.

I tried to use `sudo apt-get install python3.4-numpy` and the terminal response:

`Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.

Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
E: Paket python3.4-numpy kann nicht gefunden werden.
E: Mittels des Musters »python3.4-numpy« konnte kein Paket gefunden werden.
E: Mittels regulärem Ausdruck »python3.4-numpy« konnte kein Paket gefunden werden.`

(means: E: package python3.4-numpy can not be found or something like this)

Then I used the the alias-command `alias python=python3.4` and tried it with `sudo apt-get install python-numpy`, but there isn't a numpy module in the modules list in python3.4, instead it is in python2.7. And if I use `sudo apt-get install python3-numpy` the module is in python3.5.

I don't want to use a `virtualenv`. Do you have any ideas how I get the modules into python3.4?

(Sorry for the edit - i uploaded the question to fast.)

Comment: You can always bootstrap pip using [this](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) having some python-binary like your 3.4. Using this installed pip allows you to install numpy, but it will be build from the sources (and you need to prepare your system for that; it's all written in the docs; scipy would be a bit worse). I don't recommend it though as the anaconda-approach is 99.9% of times the better one. Every information you provided yet is no reason not to use anaconda. On the contrary: the basic feeling i get is that you would benefit a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You have expressed interests installing scientific python packages.  Consider installing a [virtual environment](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) with [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)).

Anaconda is a cross-platform python package manager that incorporates `pip`.  Therefore, whatever can be installed with `pip` and be installed reliably using the Anaconda package manager.

*Benefits*

Your benefits are twofold.  Using conda will:

1. allow you to install Python 3.4 (or any version) in an isolated environment (preserving your root Python environment, untampered)
2. install scientific packages including [numpy with less headaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20567418/error-installing-numpy)

*Steps*

1. [Download and install Anaconda](https://docs.continuum.io/Anaconda/install).  Once installed, you will have command line access to a ton of python packages using either `conda` or `pip`.
2. Build a virtual environment with `conda create --name myenv python=3.4 numpy`

That's it.  If you want to install more packages try `conda` first then `pip` if not included e.g. `conda install scipy pandas` or `pip install <packagename>`.

You can always remove an environment with `conda env remove -n <envname>`, so virtual environments are a great tool for testing reproducible environments.

Comment: I don't want to use a virtuelenv, because I need it for my scientific work with large files and other modules.

Comment: Please clarify your hesitation.  Virtualenvs are very common for scientific work.  I build and remove them all the time for my work as they do not affect your personal files.

Comment: @Mara You don't seem to understand what virtualenv is then! Take your time and read about it. Technically virtualenv and conda environments differ. But the recommendation of anaconda is very very valuable and very scientific! (On windows it's even the recommended path by the numpy/scipy-devs; nothing wrong with using it on Unix too)

Comment: Pardon my wording.  By "virtualenv" I mean virtual environment for short.  I encourage you to consider this because conda really solved a lot of problems. :)

Comment: I need to use the module snappy from the SNAP Toolbox and I read a lot about problems with snappy and virtualenv. So I want to do it without.

Comment: @Mara If it can be installed with `pip`, you can use `conda` to install it.  btw, `conda` is built by members of the scipy community, so it was made with  scientists in mind.  And remember, `virtualenv` is a package; virtual environment is a broader concept.

Comment: @sascha yes, i'm new to python. but i will try the anaconda - way. thanks.

Comment: Welcome to python @Mara and scipy!